# Where is the UV Maps Panel?

Tags: uv, interface

I am looking for the UV Maps Panel, which is "in the Mesh Tab." I am totally lost on this.

There are buttons at the top which say *View*, *Select*, *Add*, *Mesh*. When I click on the *Mesh* button there are a lot of menu items, but no *UV Maps* panel. I'm guessing that this isn't even the *Mesh* tab. I would appreciate the info.

[image]

Comment: it's in the Properties panel > Object Data > UV Maps

Comment: Thank you - very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Just to illustrate *@moonboots'* comment.
*Properties editor > Object Data (Green Icon) > UV Maps*

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much - I never would have found it otherwise!

Comment: @JoeGideon Hello and welcome. Please don't add thank you as a comment, upvote the answer instead. If you feel it completely solved your problem consider marking it accepted